# pycurl read and set cookie without cookie file

Tags: python, curl, cookies, pycurl

i am trying to save and later use cookies with pycurl. i have to store cookies to db, so that i am not using a cookie file, i am getting cookies from set cookie line in header and cookies likes

```
main_token=d4313443f5f98d8c4deca6325d7ded9a; expires=Wed, 13-Jan-2016 13:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
main_user_id=132; expires=Tue, 14-Apr-2015 13:51:59 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/
```

i tried to set these cookies with

```
c.setopt(pycurl.CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'key=value;anotherkey=anothervalue')
```

bot not any luck, how can i set these cookies to pycurl requests ?

Comment: It's a hard problem because `pycurl` is hard-wired to use a file path as the cookie jar.  If tasked with this, I'd experiment with a userspace filesystem, per http://www.stavros.io/posts/python-fuse-filesystem/, capturing a special path and diverting I/O operations there to a special cookie jar class using the database; if I had to size the effort (to prod level including testing &c), to bill per hour, I'd assess "20 to 40 hours" with 90% chance of success.

Comment: Alex thanks for your reply, i will try to generate file from db, before generating curl operations, and after, delete the file. i think this is my best chance.

Comment: Excellent idea -- let the cookie jar do its job in the file(s), treat said file as "transient", and "persist" the cookie jar file to/from the database.  If you run into any issue implementing that generating and persisting, edit the Q or post another one w/more details on how you want the cookies in the DB.  If you're worried about a crash losing you the updated cookie jar, you can also do things incrementally (check the cookie jar and persist any new/changed tokens to the DB after each `pycurl` interaction) though maybe that could be a tad slow.